# Is having a model method output a single HTML element a violation of MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic

I sometimes will add model methods like so:

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = CharField(length=64)

    @classmethod
    def dropdown(cls, classes="" id_prefix=""):
       """
       Prints out a select box with every company
       """
       if id_prefix:
           id_prefix = id_prefix +  '_'
       t = Template("""
         <select class="{{ classes }}" id="{{ id_prefix }}company_id">
         {% for company in companies %}
         <option value="{{ company.id }}">{{ company.name }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
         </select>
       """)
       companies = cls.objects.all()
       c = {'companies': companies, 'classes': classes, 'id_prefix': id_prefix}
       return t.render(c)
```

A lot of my coworkers tell me that this is wrong because outputting HTML is something that should always be done in the view, but my thinking is that since it's just a single HTML element, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether it's a single `<` or a whole page; the model is supposed to return *display neutral data*. How that data is displayed is entirely the job of the view. Just think about *alternative views*. What if you want to make an API that receives and returns JSON? You'll still use the same model to manipulate the data, but there's no HTML involved whatsoever. So what is the HTML specific method doing in the model?

Comment: a single HTML element _is_ display neutral data, the way I see it. The CSS and HTML surrounding the select element is what handles how the data is being displayed (which is still controlled by the view).

Comment: Even a single HTML element is ***HTML***. Again, what if you want to reuse the model in a completely non-HTML context? HTML is a specific form of output format, which is clearly the view's job.